# Circuitlab - How can I create my own transistor model?

Tags: transistors, modeling, circuitlab

I would like to create some transistors, like the S8050 transistor, for to use in CircuitLab.

What I found is https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/custom-device-models/

If I open another existing transistor, then I see variable namings that give me no clue about what I should place in their fields. Is there an example somewhere that shows how to do this, or a YT film, or an other explanation of this?

Comment: 1) What are you hoping to achieve with creating your own model? 2) The S8050 is a very standard NPN transistor, in 8 out of 10 circuits you would not notice much difference if you used a similar NPN transistor but feel free to show me your circuit and explain why an S8050 model is needed. 4) asking where to find a certain explanation is **off topic**.

Comment: CircuitLab has an "Import SPICE Model" button. If you paste in a .MODEL card, it will extract the relevant bits. You will need to first find such a model for the device. But that often isn't too hard, searching the web. So that is one approach. The other will be setting up various test-bench arrangements, learning about each parameter, and making measurements. Which are you more likely to do?

Comment: @jonk Thank you, I will try to search the web. If I am right, I can adjust the imported Spice model anytime in CircuitLab.

Comment: Circuit simulator design is not taught as a regular UG course; some schools offer it as an elective. If you have a background in EE, try taking a grad course on simulator design.